# Owl carousel URL Hash Navigation

Tags: wordpress

Как в цикле wordpress получить правильный `data-hash` айтема из карусели, чтобы можно было переходить к нужному слайду как в примере на официальном сайте [Url Hash Navigation](http://www.owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/urlhashnav.html)
Сейчас у меня такая разметка:

```html
<ul class="list-inline">
 <li><a href="#all" class="active">Все</a></li>
 <li><a href="#events">Мероприятия</a></li>
 <li><a href="#news">Новости</a></li>
 <li><a href="#collections">Коллекции</a></li>
 <li><a href="#stocks">Акции и скидки</a></li>
</ul>


<div class="main_carousel">

<?php
$args = array('cat'=>'6');
query_posts($args);
while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
?>

 <div class="carousel_item" data-hash=" ">
  <img src="<?php the_field('slider_news_img'); ?>" alt="Alt">
 </div>

<?php endwhile; wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php $wp_query1 = $temp_query1; ?>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решено:

```html
<div class="carousel_item" data-hash="<?php
    $category = get_the_category(); 
    $last_category = end($category);
    echo $last_category->slug;
    ?>" >
```

Answer (score 0):

`ID` поста — уникальное значение, которое подходит под эту роль

```
<div class="carousel_item" data-hash="<? echo $post->ID; ?>">
```

Comment: Не подходит к сожалению. У меня картинки для слайдера находятся в 4-х разных категориях с ярлыками: events, news, collections, stocks, и получается после нажатия на ссылку <a href="#events"> нужен переход к слайду из категории с ярлыком events, вот и вопрос: как для этого слайда брать ярлык чтобы записать его в  data-hash

Comment: 5 раз перечитал. Ничего не понял. Бросил. Может кто-то другой поймет. п.с. напишите в первом вопросе все четко и понятно. сейчас каша какая-то